# How can I have a command-line argument -h with Python's argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I have the following python:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
requiredNamed = parser.add_argument_group('required named arguments')
requiredNamed.add_argument('-h', '--host_name', required=True, help="Host IP address")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

This produces the following error:

```
argparse.ArgumentError: argument -h/--help: conflicting option string(s): -h
```

Every single letter works fine except `-h`. It seems like it is reserved for --help. How can I make it so that it isn't `-h` isn't automatically reserved?

Comment: If you're building a command line program, you should seriously consider keeping `-h` for help -- it's a very long standing tradition in the *nix community, and your users might be confused and surprised by the non-standard behavior of -H. Perhaps you can use `-H` for the short version of `--host_name`.

Comment: my script is mimicking the `mysql` command line interface. This interface uses `-h` to refer to the hostname. So I would like to match that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**`ArgumentParser`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser) takes an optional parameter `add_help` which you can set `False`.

In the documentation for [`add_help`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#add-help):

> Occasionally, it may be useful to disable the addition of this help option. This can be achieved by passing `False` as the `add_help=` argument to `ArgumentParser`:
>
> ```
> >>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG', add_help=False)  
> >>> parser.add_argument('--foo', help='foo help')
> >>> parser.print_help()
> usage: PROG [--foo FOO]
>
> optional arguments:
>  --foo FOO  foo help
> ```